# Do I really need to define mapping association in my entities?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using symfony 2.4 and doctrine, I have struggled coming up with the right mapping for relations in my entities classes.

**Question:** Do I really have to do it? Or can I just use joins in my repositories classes? I feel more comfortable with the latter, are there any drawbacks if just use joins?

Comment: You'd be absolutely crazy not to define mappings in your entities. For the sake of your app's quality, performance and everyone around you, do it!

Comment: You can write sql and just do joins.  You won't get the automatic object mapping for your entities.  Which would be a bit sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: if you don't wont to do it why do you use doctrine? It's really powerful tool and in my opinion, one of the most important part of this library.

If you need help with defining relations please don't hesitate to put a short code here. We can find a solution. In the beginning it's always hard to understand, but after creating a very first well mapped entities it becomes to be pretty clear how and why to do that.

It's of course possible to avoid defining relations, but after-effects will be painful.